# Topological Manifold covered by Compact Sets

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, compactness

Let $M$ be a topological manifold. Is that true that there always exist  compact sets $K_n$ with the property $\bigcup_n K_n = M$ and $K_n \subset K ^{\circ} _{n+1}$.

The problem is that this is true is $M$ is a CW complex or has countable base. But does it hold also generally?

Comment: If your definition of "manifold" contains the conditions Hausdorff and second countable, then yes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustion_by_compact_sets

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Well, with second countableness the statement is is indeed trivial. What about the case if we don't have this condition? Do you have a conterexample?

Answer (score 1):

The usual definition of manifold is such that every manifold is second countable. Then, has you wrote, there is such a sequence of compact sets. On the other hand, if you don't assume that, such a sequence doesn't have to exist. Imagine, say, an infinite uncountable union of copies of $\mathbb R$.